# Do the CM value in the image editor already take the displays gamma curve in consideration?

Tags: color-management

[image]

Does Blender account for the fact that my display applies a gamma curve and appropriately apply the inverse gamma curve, or does Blender just send this value to my display, meaning that what is on my screen is actually darker than the number given by CM?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a different way of asking your [most recent previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/264538/42221); except it introduces the issue of *monitor calibration*.

Blender displays what the image should look like when it displays an image on your monitor, provided:

- You've correctly told Blender what color space that image is using; and
- You have a *calibrated* monitor.  Users rarely have properly calibrated monitors.

See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/264545/42221) for more details.

Comment: My question was about the numbers Blender displays right to CM. I am aware that if I tell Blender that I have a sRGB display it will at some point apply an inverse sRGB gamma curve, so that my image is displayed correctly provided my display is calibrated correctly. My question is: Are those the numbers that already have that inverse sRGB gamma curve applied, or does Blender do it at a later stage?